# Darktable 2.4.4 image info module showing 160 for lens, instead of lens name

Tags: nikon, darktable, lensfun

I'm using Darktable 2.4.4 on Linux Mint 19 Xfce. I have updated Lensfun (v0.3.2.4). How do I get my 18-55 lens to be automatically recognized?

My Nikon D5300 is recognized, no problem, but the kit lens (Nikon AF-P DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR) shows in the "image module" on the right hand side as lens "160" instead of the lens name.

I have to manually select the lens in the lens correction module every time (it is listed, so it's there). The lens is listed as '160' and says, "Camera/lens not found-please select manually" (which you can). This can be tedious. I'm positive this lens (Nikon AF-P DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR)  worked automatically with Darktable in an earlier version.

When I put my Sigma 17-50mm on D5300 everything works automatically in Darktable as expected. I've spent a ton of time googling and trying things for a solution, but so far I've got nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Darktable depends on `exiv2`, not lensfun, for lens name mappings. You may not have this lens mapping if it's an older version of `exiv2`. To compound the problem, `exiv2` [faces some difficulties when it comes to accurately providing this information](http://dev.exiv2.org/issues/1306), so even recent versions may exhibit this problem for some lenses. If updating to exiv2 0.26 or later doesn't solve the problem, the [suggested solution](http://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/wiki/Lens_Recognition_in_Exiv2_v026_(and_later)/) is for users to provide their own mappings for the lenses they use.

In your case, this would probably be something like:

`[nikon]
160=Nikon AF-P DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR`

added to the `~/.exiv2` file (you'll need to create it if it doesn't already exist).

Note that updating `exiv2` will require rebuilding darktable along with any other applications that use the library.